Canonical divisor of punctured K3 surface
Let $X$ be a complex K3 surfaces. In particular, the canonical divisor $K_X$ of $X$ is trivial. Now consider $\hat{X}=X\setminus \{\text{finite number of points}\}$. What can we say about its canonical divisor? I hope it is trivial as well but where do I start? I was thinking about a way to conclude that $H^0(\hat{X},K_{\hat{X}})=\mathbb{C}$.

Yes, it is trivial. A line bundle is trivial if and only if it has a non-vanishing global section. The restriction of a non-vanishing holomorphic 2-form from $X$ to $\widehat{X}$ is certainly still non-vanishing. (You can even delete a curve from $X$ and the result is still true.)
